# Some optimization involving convexity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am reviewing some stuff in analysis/PDE. Given a function $F$ :$\mathbb{R}^n$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following condition: given any constant $C >0$, $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n F_{x_i,x_j}(x)\lambda_i\lambda_j \geq C|\lambda|^2$ for any $x, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Use Taylor's formula to show that, for any $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $F(\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}) \leq \frac{1}{2}F(v_1) + \frac{1}{2}F(v_2) - \frac{C}{8}|v_1-v_2|^2$. 
At the moment, I don't quite know where to start. Any help or guide is tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint:

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and
$\phi''(t) \ge c$. Then for some $\xi \in [t_0,t]$
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(t) &=& \phi(t_0) + \phi'(t_0)(t-t_0) + {1 \over 2} \phi''(\xi) (t-t_0)^2 \\
&\ge& \phi(t_0) + \phi'(t_0)(t-t_0) + {1 \over 2} C (t-t_0)^2
\end{eqnarray}

Then
$\phi(t_1) \ge \phi({t_1+t_2 \over 2} )+ \phi'({t_1+t_2 \over 2})({t_1-t_2 \over 2})  + {1 \over 2} C ({t_1-t_2 \over 2} )^2 $ and
$\phi(t_2) \ge \phi({t_1+t_2 \over 2} )+ \phi'({t_1+t_2 \over 2})({t_2-t_1 \over 2})  + {1 \over 2} C ({t_1-t_2 \over 2} )^2 $
which gives
$\phi(t_1)+ \phi(t_2) \ge 2\phi({t_1+t_2 \over 2} ) + C ({t_1-t_2 \over 2} )^2$.

For the $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ case, we just reduce to
the single variable case as follows:

Let $\phi(t) = F(tv_1 + (1-t) v_2), t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1$ and note that
$\phi''(t) = \langle v_1-v_2, {\partial^2 F(tv_1 + (1-t) v_2) \over \partial x^2}  (v_1-v_2) \ge C \|v_1-v_2\|^2 $.

Comment: Nvm, I think I figured it out. The only thing left is when we apply Taylor's formula, didn't we have some error term left, which is dependent on our choice of $t$ ?

Comment: No, it is lower bounded by the lower bound on the Hessian.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that again? We have some $O(t)$  term and $\phi(t)$ is lower bounded by $\phi(t) + \phi'(t_o) +1/2 \phi''(t_o)(t-t_o)^2 +O(t-t_0)$, is that right ?

Comment: I am not sure what $O(t)$ term you are referring to? There are no terms missing above as far as I can tell. The second equation above comes from the mean value theorem.

Comment: Oh I think I understand for method now. I was just following the Taylor formula for $\phi$ with the multi-index given by $\phi(t)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} \frac{1}{\alpha!}D^\alpha\phi(t_0)(t-t_0)^{\alpha} + O((t-t_o)^{k+1}) $ for $k$=1,2,...

Comment: That formula doesn't have an explicit form of the remainder so it is not possible to get rid of the $O(t^3)$ term. The mean value has an explicit form (except that there is no formula for the $\xi$, of course) so we can obtain a hard bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. It was very helpful.

Comment: You are very welcome.